# I want to add the ImagePlugin to the ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, centos, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to add the ImagePlugin to the ElasticSearch.

It will be added location is not connected network.
so, I am trying to use download plugin from another connected network location.
But even doing many times, same error message will be displayed.

The introduction to the environment

```
centOS
install file:elasticsearch-image-master.zip
java : 1.8.0_60
ElasticSearch : 1.1.0
lucene version : 4.7
```

Install command

```
elasticsearch/bin/plugin -u file///bin/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-image-master.zip -i com.github.kzwang/elasticsearch-image/1.3.0
```

Error Message

```
Message:
Error while installing plugin, reason: IllegalArgumentException:
Plugin installation assumed to be site plugin, but contains source
code, aborting installation.
```

Excuse me, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install the .zip file that contains the source code of the plugin instead of packaged and compiled plugin. After downloading the source code you need to run `mvn clean package` in the root directory of the plugin source and install .zip file found in the target directory of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I had been a mistake. That is The downloaded file is source code.
This file is built using the Maven, I'll try and try again.

Thank you.